# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO table that does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some temp table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_test (
col1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
col2 CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
col3 BOOLEAN);
```

Then I do some inserts into `temp_test` (that works fine).

Later, **without** creating a new table `test`, I try doing the following:

```
INSERT INTO test(col1,col2,col3) SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM temp_tes;
```

And I get the following error:
`ERROR: relation "test" does not exist`

I thought that if I'm using `INSERT INTO`, it should create the table for me. does it not?

If it matters, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.16.

Comment: Use `create table .. as select` that's the recommended way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong.  `INSERT` inserts into an existing table; it does not create a table.

If you want to create a table, use `CREATE TABLE AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
    SELECT col1, ol2, col3
    FROM temp_tes;
```

Comment: What about `SELECT col1,col2,col3 INTO test FROM temp_test;`? It should work as in: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-selectinto.html, but I get now `"ERROR: "test" is not a known variable"` (I'm not using any kind of quotes)...

Comment: @ChikChak . . . Forgot Postgres supports this as well.  I usually use `create table as`, because that is consistent across more databases.  As the documentation you point to states:  "`CREATE TABLE AS` is the recommended syntax".